# Minha aplicação não reconhece meu Bean

Tags: jsf-2.2, cdi, java-bean

Observem bem a figura;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

veja como está minha classe Bean

```
package br.com.terezinha.adm.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Modelo;


@Named
@ViewScoped 
public class CadastroImovelBean implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Modelo modelo;


    public CadastroImovelBean(){
        modelo = new Modelo();
    }

    public void salvar(){

    }


    public Modelo getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(Modelo modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }





}
```

Era para está reconhecendo minha classe Bean, o que posso fazer para resolver isso?

Quando tento inserir o código na mão gera esse erro;

```
11:52:41,755 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
11:52:41,755 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" started in 11967ms - Started 279 of 333 services (92 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
11:53:04,138 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (default task-2) Error Rendering View[/imovel/CadastroImovel.xhtml]: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /imovel/CadastroImovel.xhtml @43,57 value="#{cadastroImovelBean.modelo.valorImovel}": The class 'br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Modelo' does not have the property 'valorImovel'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:81) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:131) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:102) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Modelo' does not have the property 'valorImovel'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:351) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 51 more

11:53:04,149 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Terezinha.Adm/imovel/CadastroImovel.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: /imovel/CadastroImovel.xhtml @43,57 value="#{cadastroImovelBean.modelo.valorImovel}": The class 'br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Modelo' does not have the property 'valorImovel'.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_31]
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /imovel/CadastroImovel.xhtml @43,57 value="#{cadastroImovelBean.modelo.valorImovel}": The class 'br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Modelo' does not have the property 'valorImovel'.
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:291) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:81) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeDynamicBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:131) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableBody(PanelGridRenderer.java:102) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeTableLayout(PanelGridRenderer.java:65) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at org.primefaces.component.panelgrid.PanelGridRenderer.encodeEnd(PanelGridRenderer.java:37) [primefaces-5.2.jar:5.2]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Modelo' does not have the property 'valorImovel'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:351) [jboss-el-api_3.0_spec-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: É comum ocorrer do import no teu jsp não estar funcionando corretamente. Nesse caso faça-o n mão e efetue o teste.

Comment: gerou um erro e postei o erro na pagina, dá uma olhada, pois acabei de atualizar minha postagem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The class 'br.com.terezinha.adm.model.Modelo' does not have the
>   property 'valorImovel'.

Veja a tua classe modelo não tem o atributo "valorImovel"